# How to post UTF-8 text from MySQL to Twitter successfully

Tags: mysql, perl, twitter, character-encoding

I have some text in UTF-8. I put it into a MySQL database, collation `utf8_general_ci` and then I've been auto-posting it to Twitter via Net::Twitter.

But when I post it, even though Twitter itself seems to be expecting UTF-8, going by the content-type in their input pages, I'm getting those artefacts you get when UTF-8 text is misinterpreted: é comes out as Ã© for instance.

So ... at what point is this going wrong? How can I ensure it makes the trip undamaged?

- Set my script to treat all text as UTF-8 somehow?
- Make sure I extract it from the database in UTF-8?
- Tell Net::Twitter that it's posting in UTF-8?

Comment: Sorry about the delay. Neither of the two answers below worked, I'm afraid, but what did was simply using `utf8::decode($string);` on the string extracted from the database.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to enable the [`mysql_enable_utf8`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBD%3a%3amysql#mysql_enable_utf8) attribute when opening your db connection:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=test;host=localhost",
                       "user", "password",
                       { mysql_enable_utf8 => 1});
```

This will tell Perl that strings retrieved from the database are UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: That's very much assuming that the problem is on the DBI side, and I'm pretty sure it's not.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be the encoding of the database connection, which often is `iso-8859-1` by default. That would explain the `Ã©` - it's a two-byte UTF-8 character displayed in single-byte iso-8859-1.

Does sending a query with `SET NAMES utf8;` after connecting help? (Or whatever specific command Perl's mySQL client library might have for setting the connection character set.)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [here](http://blog.zois.co.uk/2012/07/twitter-perl-and-utf-8/).

Instead of

```
$r = $nt->update ( { 'status' => $message } );
```

Try

```
use Encode;
$r = $nt->update ( { 'status' => decode( 'utf-8' ,  $message ) } ) ;
```